# Import Java EE project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I want to import an existing project into Eclipse. So I saw a simple method : **File > Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace** but when I try to add my repertory, it says : "*No Projects are found to import*". Maybe I didn't understande what is a "project", I don't really know because it's not my project, I didn't developp it.

Should I open a file in particular ?

Please help me !

EDIT:

Maybe I must change some properties in Eclipse ?

Comment: Maybe there is no Eclipse project file. If its not an Eclipse project already you might be better off creating a new project and then importing the files.

Comment: This can happen when the project is not developed in Eclipse, but in a different IDE. Just choose "Import archive file" or "Import WAR" option instead.

Comment: @BalusC Where is this option please ?

Comment: @BalusC Ok, I found, but I can't select all the files, how sould I do ?

Comment: @BalusC Ok, I found it, and it works, thanks a lot ! Could you add an answer to validate the post please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So I saw a simple method : File > Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace*

This works only if it's a true Eclipse project. I.e. it has an Eclipse-compatible `.project` file and `/.settings` folder.

If it doesn't work out for you, then it apparently isn't an Eclipse project. You should then import it as a general project. If it's a ZIP file, import it as *General > Archive File*. Or, if it's a WAR file, import it as *Web > WAR file*. Or, if it's an expanded WAR file structure (basically, an unzipped WAR file), import it as *General > File System*.

After the import, it will be auto-converted to a true Eclipse project. You can if necessary configure the project facets by *Rightclick Project > Properties > Project Facets*, and/or reconfigure the project structure by *Rightclick Project > Configure*.

Comment: I love the way how BalusC answer questions. I'm very much impreseed.